# $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$ such that prime $a + b + 1 > c + 1$. If $k_n = (n + 1)$, then $k_1\dots k_c | (k_{b + 1} - k_a) \dots (k_{b+c} - k_a)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have natural numbers $a, b, c$ such that $a + b + 1$ is a prime greater than $c + 1$. I need to prove that if $k_n = n(n + 1)$, $(k_{b + 1} - k_a)(k_{b+2} - k_a)\dots(k_{b + c} - k_a)$ is divisible by $k_1k_2\dots k_c$. I have no idea where to begin on this, and have just managed to simplify the divisor to $c!(c+1)!$
Could I please get some help? A hint would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $k_{b+i}-k_a = (b+a+i+1)(b-a+i)$

Comment: that is an absurd factorisation, how'd you get that?

Comment: $c(c+1)-a(a+1) = c^2+c-a^2-a=(c^2-a^2)+(c-a)=(c+a)(c-a)+(c-a)=(c+a+1)(c-a)$

Comment: ah, i see. i think i can solve the rest of the question from here. thanks for your assistance!

Comment: If you found the answer useful, you could accept it.